# How to make the background image overflow with youtube video

Tags: html, css

I have a youtube video in one HTML section which is responsive.
When I resize the browser the youtube video overflows to the 2nd next section.

How do I make the background image of the first section extend with the youtube video?

[image: When browser is resized the youtube video is bigger than the background image 1. How to I resize background image 1 with the youtube video]

I need to keep it within this HTML section when it's on a mobile in Landscape mode OR I need the background image to stretch to accommodate it.

**HTML**

```css
#work {
  text-align: center;
  background: #3B3B3B url('https://bingo.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-overflow: visible;
}

#work h3 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!-- work section -->
<section id="work">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <!-- <div class="section-title"> -->
        <h1> <strong>Sample of Our Work</strong> </h1>
        <hr></hr>
        <!-- </div>  -->
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 ">
        <div class="video-container">
          <div class="video-wrapper">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qDgWfVqG_3E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Put some code in your question around what you have tried? Create a fiddle or codepen enable us to help you. Thanks.

Comment: i think you should make your video responsive also, please prefer this for responsive video. http://fitvidsjs.com/

Comment: @Rohan It's already responsive.

Answer (score 0):

No worries all.

I simply removed the CSS and replaced it with

```css
#work {
text-align: center;
    background: #3B3B3B url('https:screaming buzzrd.jpg') no-repeat center center;  
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
    height: 100vh;


}


.video-wrapper {position: relative; 
         padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */  
         padding-top: 25px; 
         margin: auto;}
.video-wrapper iframe {position: absolute; 
              top: 20%; 
           left: 25%; 
           width: 100%; 
           height: 100%;
}
.container {width: 100%;  margin: auto; }
```